# Выделение памяти под двумерный массив в классе C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пытаюсь вот таким образом выделить память под матрицу в классе. Значения элементам массива не присваиваются. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, решение проблемы.

```
class matrix {
  double **A;
  double **B;
  double **C;
  public:
  matrix(int k)
  {
     double **A = new double*[k];
     double **B = new double*[k];
     double **C = new double*[k];
     for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
     {
        A[i] = new double[k];
        B[i] = new double[k];
        C[i] = new double[k];
     }
  }

  void enter(int k)
  {
     cout << "Введите элементы матриц: " << endl;
     cout << "A:" << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            cout << "A[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 << "]=";
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
     }
     cout << "B:" << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            cout << "B[" << i + 1 << "][" << i + 1 << "]=";
            cin >> B[i][i];
        }
     }
   }
};
```

Comment: Вы зря удалили вопрос, он не так уж плох (и его, кстати, можно восстановить). Но лучше всё же не акцентировать внимание на домашнем задании, а на реальной проблеме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструкторе класса

```
matrix(int k)
{
    double **A = new double*[k];
    double **B = new double*[k];
    double **C = new double*[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new double[k];
        B[i] = new double[k];
        C[i] = new double[k];
    }
}
```

вы объявили локальные переменные `A`, `B` и `C` и для них выделяете память

```
double **A = new double*[k];
double **B = new double*[k];
double **C = new double*[k];
```

Уберите объявления и запешите

```
matrix(int k)
{
    A = new double*[k];
    B = new double*[k];
    C = new double*[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new double[k];
        B[i] = new double[k];
        C[i] = new double[k];
    }
}
```

Желательно, чтобы конструктор инициализировал элементы массивов нулем по умолчанию. Поэтому память для каждой "строки" массивов следует выделять следующим образом

```
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new double[k]();
        B[i] = new double[k]();
        C[i] = new double[k]();
    }
```

Естественно проще было бы использовать стандартный контейнер `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` вместо динамически распределяемых массивов.

Имейте в виду, что размерность массивов должна быть свойством самого класса. То есть вам следует объявить еще член данных класса для хранения размерности массивов. Поэтому функция-член класса `enter` должна быть объявлена без параметра

```
void enter();
```

И не забудьте написать деструктор. А также либо сделайте удаленными конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания, либо их явно определите.

Comment: @Александр Ефремов Не за что. Обращайтесь еще.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix(int k)
{
   double **A = new double*[k];
   double **B = new double*[k];
   double **C = new double*[k];
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
   {
       A[i] = new double[k];
       B[i] = new double[k];
       C[i] = new double[k];
   }
 }
```

В конструкторе вы объявляете новые локальные переменные, а вам нужно выделять память для полей класса.